# Translation of "无论如何, 你一定要平安"

Tags: translation, grammar

Does this mean "Anyway, you must be safe" or "Anyway, you are certainly safe"?

I think it is the former, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

无论如何 means "no matter what"

The verb 要 means "need **to be**" here in this sentence, because it is followed by an adjective 平安(safe).

一定**要**平安 means " **need to be**  safe for sure"

If the verb 要 is followed by a noun, for example 一定要一千美元, then 要 would simply mean "need" - "need $1000 for sure"

*If the verb 要 is followed by another verb, then 要 would be a modal verb in the sentence, for example: "you need to kill him"*

Comment: Does this translate roughly to "No matter what, you definitely need to be safe"?

Comment: *Does this translate roughly to "No matter what, you definitely need to be safe"*   -- It is correct.

Answer (score 5):

无论如何，你一定要平安。
Whatever goes down, yo ass gotta stay in one piece. (US)
No matter how, you must stay safe. (UK)

I would put 你一定要 as you must, you gotta

Comment: I like this answer because it's funny and it's true depending on who is interpreting it.

Comment: A bit of fun is important! I am a big fan of Negro American, it is so refreshingly different to English.

Comment: Please be safe, no matter what. - to me, the original sentence sounds like what a girl would say to her boyfriend when he goes to a war. So this is how I would translate it. But English is not my first language, so I won't write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact translation, but this is how we(or I) would say it in English:
- No matter what (happens), be sure to stay safe.

Side note:
"Be sure" would be more like 务必 (be sure to)

Also, props to the wicked street translation haha